# MS Word vba rearange pages order

Tags: vba, ms-word

How to reverse all page order, so page 1,2,3,4,5 become 5,4,3,2,1  as this do Option.Reverse while printing.

as

```
Sub test()
Dim WA As Object, WD As Object
Dim rngDoc As Word.Range, rngInsert As Word.Range
    Set WA = CreateObject("Word.Application")
    Set WD = WA.Documents.Add(TemplatesName)
    Set rngDoc = WD.Content
    Set rngInsert = rngDoc.Duplicate
        For i = 1 To 100
            With rngInsert
                .InsertBreak Type:=wdSectionBreakNextPage
                .MoveEnd Unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=-1 ' this one reversing pages
                .InsertFile TemplatesName
            End With
        Next i
    WD.SaveAs PdfFile, 17
    WD.Close False: Set WD = Nothing
    WA.Quit False: Set WA = Nothing
End Sub
```

Insert pages in Reverse order, I need reverse them back

Option.reverse with

```
WA.PrintOut OutputFileName:=PdfFile, Range:=wdPrintAllDocument, Item:= _
            wdPrintDocumentWithMarkup, Copies:=1, Pages:="", PageType:= _
            wdPrintAllPages, Collate:=True, Background:=True, PrintToFile:=True, _
            PrintZoomColumn:=0, PrintZoomRow:=0, PrintZoomPaperWidth:=0, _
            PrintZoomPaperHeight:=0
```

do what i need but here apears warning about wrong margings, so if i set displayalert to False then document not saving.

Comment: What is the point of reversing the page order in the first place? As for reverting to the original, simply close the document without saving the changes. Alternatively, run the macro a second time.

Comment: I think problem is in formatings, but I cant change them in more than 1000 document.
`.InsertFile TemplatesName` insert document on top of previous page instead on bottom, so first page goes second after inserting new page and etc.

Comment: I believe the term you should be using in your various questions is "MARGINS". You need to be more specific about what you mean by "formattings". Apparently, the problem you're having has something to do with page margins, but it's not clear what the problem is. Based on your previous questions, I think you should edit in a description that goes something like: I'm trying to insert the same template file into my document multiple times. That works using the code in [link to that question], but when I try to [what?] there's a problem. [Describe what the problem is]. How can I avoid that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can reverse the print order, if that's what you're after, via:

```
Options.PrintReverse = True
```

However, if the problem is that you're inserting the pages in the wrong order, you need code like:

```
Sub Demo()
Dim wdApp As New Word.Application, wdDoc As Word.Document
Dim wdRng As Word.Range, i As Long
Const TemplatesName As String = "Template Path & name"
Set wdDoc = wdApp.Documents.Add(TemplatesName)
Set wdRng = wdDoc.Range
For i = 1 To 10
  With wdRng
    .InsertAfter vbCr
    .Start = wdDoc.Range.End
    .InsertBreak Type:=wdSectionBreakNextPage
    .Collapse wdCollapseEnd
    .InsertFile TemplatesName
  End With
Next i
End Sub
```